# MYSQL and Tomcat bug

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, javabeans

Hi guys i have a bug with tomcat and mysql. Indeed, with this servlet code :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        BeanBDAccess b = new BeanBDAccess("MYSQL","mysql_bd_societe","sadik","sadikano");
        //BeanBDAccess b = new BeanBDAccess("ORACLE","XE","sadik","sadikano");

        b.connectDB();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet LoginServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet LoginServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        String nom =request.getParameter("nom");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        if(nom != null && pwd!=null)
        {
            ResultSet rs=null;
            try 
            {
                out.println("<p>Before ExecuteQuey</p>");
                rs = b.executeQuery("SELECT * from Clients where login = '"+nom+"' AND password = '"+pwd+"';");
                out.println("<p>After ExecuteQuery</p>");
                if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())
                    out.println("<p>Erreur de connexion, utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrecte</p>");
                else
                    out.println("<p>Connexion réussie !</p>");
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                out.println("<p>Erreur"+ex.getMessage()+"</p>");
        }
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

This serlvet is in a web project created with Netbeans 8.1. The servlet uses a bean to access to a DataBase. This bean has 2 functions used in the servlet :

```
public synchronized ResultSet executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException
{
    java.sql.Statement instruc = null;
    try {
        instruc = con.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BeanBDAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("Création d'une instance d'instruction pour cette connexion");
    rs = instruc.executeQuery(query);
    return rs;
}
```

That's the function which execute a query.

```
public boolean connectDB()
{
    boolean ret=true;
    try
    {
        if(type == "MYSQL")
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            urlDB = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+urlDB;
            System.out.println("Driver MYSQL chargé");
        }
        else if(type=="ORACLE")
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            urlDB = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:"+urlDB;
            System.out.println("Driver ORACLE chargé");
        }

    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Driver adéquat non trouvable : " + e.getMessage());
        ret=false;
    }
    try
    {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB,user,password);
        System.out.println("Connexion à la BDD réalisée");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Erreur SQL : " + e.getMessage());
        ret=false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And connectDB() is the function which connects to the DB

When i use this bean in a sample java.class main, it works but when it's executed on the tomcat server (ont the web project - Servlet) it blocks a the instruction :

```
rs = b.executeQuery("SELECT * from Clients where login = '"+nom+"' AND password = '"+pwd+"';");
```

And the most weird thing is that nothing is execute after this line, and no Exception is thrown. The generated HTML page is not completed, given that nothing is execute after b.executeQuery(...); :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Servlet LoginServlet</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Servlet LoginServlet at /CaddieVirtuel</h1>
<p>Before ExecuteQuey</p>
```

To finish, when i used the same code but with a different database (another conenction) :

//BeanBDAccess b = new BeanBDAccess("ORACLE","XE","sadik","sadikano");

It works ... And to finish, the same code on another computer give me the result i want ...

Ty for reading, and i'm realy sorry for my english ...

Comment: Without reading all that stuff, but only your SELECT statement - did you ever hear something about SQL injection?

Comment: Oh, and do not include the semicolon in JDBC statements.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Hi, ty for answering, Yeah i heard something about SQL injection, but for the moment i'm only testing ... I think this is not the problem here.

Comment: Your JDBC url points to "localhost", i.e. you must run that code on the same machine as the MySQL database host.

Comment: That's what i did,  the servlet is used on  a tomcat  server which is launched in the same machine than mysql server (localhost but on différents ports)

Comment: `catch (SQLException ex) { ... }` is the reason for `no Exception is thrown`? You're swallowing the complete stacktrace; so you cannot see any stacktrace if an SQLException or ClassNotFoundException is thrown.

Comment: @ujulu ty for information that help me a lot ... u were right a exception was trown in connectDB() and ExecuteQuery(...) but i could only see it on the Tomcat console and not on my servlet.

i had this on the tomcat loggs Erreur SQL : No suitable driver found for mysql_bd_societe (print when the exception was thrown).

i have add the mysql driver at my project, now everything is ok, i can continue. Thank you very much for the help.